# Unable to load dynamic library 'ldap' in MacOS

Tags: php, php-extension, php-ini

I reinstalled php with brew in Macos:

```
brew reinstall php@8.2
```

In php.ini I found out this line and removed (;):

```
extension=ldap
```

As I restarted php service brew, when I:

```
php -i | grep extension_dir
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ldap' (tried: ....
```

It seems ldap is not installed (I was expecting brew to install it).

How can I overcome with this problem in Macos?

Comment: install ldap: `brew install php-ldap` then restart php